# Android fragments onClick connect with method

Tags: android

I have the problem with connect method of button in fragment.
It doesn't work ... my application is always closed when I click a button.
In normal activity it work correctly, but why not in fragments? How can I repare it?

```
<Button
            android:id="@+id/button1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:onClick="green"
            android:text="@string/green" />
```

and

```
View rootview;
@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    rootview = inflater.inflate(R.layout.menu1_layout, container, false);

return rootview;
}
```

and my method green

```
public void green(View v){

    //here everything is good
       }
```

import android.view.View.OnClickListener; is marked "is never used"

Comment: I would recommend not using the android:onClick and use an onClickListener instead

Comment: I tried it but I don't know why it doesn't work. OnClick seems to be more clear

Comment: try removing @Nullable annotation, and also post the Activity code which loads this fragment

Comment: your problem is your onCreateView in your fragment, this should only return the view. then you want to override the onViewCreated method in your fragment to reference the UI elements. see edit below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot do this since there is no context reference to a Fragment without the Activity. So therefore this is only possible in an Activity not a Fragment. Important thing to note here is that your Fragment must call getActivity() to find a reference to the context, since a fragment can be placed in any Activity fragment's themselves really have no context so referencing a Fragment's method in xml will not be possible in this respect.

Directly from Android :

> public static final int onClick                        added in API 4
>
> Name of the method in this View's context to invoke when the view is clicked. This name must correspond to a public method that takes exactly one parameter of type View. For instance, if you specify android:onClick="sayHello", you must declare a public void sayHello(View v) method of your context (typically, your Activity).
>
> Must be a string value, using '\;' to escape characters such as '\n' or '\uxxxx' for a unicode character.
>
> This may also be a reference to a resource (in the form "@[package:]type:name") or theme attribute (in the form "?[package:][type:]name") containing a value of this type.
>
> Constant Value: 16843375 (0x0101026f)

**UPDATE**

Just Use this then:

```
Button button = (Button) getView().findViewById(R.id.button1);
button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
   public void onClick(View v) {
        // Move your green(View v) method logic here instead of calling green(v)
   }
});
```

**UPDATE 2**

your fragment code should be doing this before anything else:

```
public class menu1_fragment extends Fragment {
      View rootview;
      @Override
     public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
           rootview = inflater.inflate(R.layout.menu1_layout, container, false); 
        return rootview;
    }

     // Probably safer for you to use onViewCreated(View, Bundle)
     @Override
     public void onViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState){
         super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
          // use rootView or getView()
          Button button = (Button) rootView.findViewById(R.id.button1);
             button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                 public void onClick(View v) {
                  // Move your green(View v) method logic here instead of calling  green(v)
                }
          });
     }
 }
```

you cannot reference a UI element before the View is inflated, which was the cause of your error. Alternatively you can use  `onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState)`.

Comment: For every method ( `code android:onClick="com.example.photoeditor.menu1_fragment.green" `)

Comment: with UPDATE it stops and closes my application

Comment: So everything which I in normal (without Fragments) Activity place in OnCreate, in Fragments I should to implement in onActivityCreated ?

Comment: its probably safest to place UI references in onViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) because this method is called once your view has been created meaning that its safe to reference UI elements. Please see update above.

Comment: That's great, so can I ask you what does it do `super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);` ?

Comment: this makes a call to the super class which is android.app.Fragment.onViewCreated(View, Bundle) method.